# Twilio Studio - Access DTMF Digits from a <gather> returned by a function?

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-twiml

Is there any way while inside a Twilio Studio Flow to access Digits from a TwiML Gather that has been returned from a function inside the flow?

---

I am using Twilio Studio to create a rather complex call flow. At one point in the flow, I need to create a TwiML Gather with a dynamic number of options (there can be anywhere between 3 and 10 valid DTMF options).

The Twilio Function I have created works, and returns the TwiML Gather properly, but I cannot find a way to access the "Digits" result of this function's Gather once the user presses a key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Currently once you pass a call off to a Function you can't return control to a Studio Flow.

However, the good news is that the feature is in progress. I don't have an ETA for it yet though, but I will report back here when it is possible with instructions on how.

Answer (score 0):

You can now return back to the studio flow and call the digits with {{widgets.YOUR_FUNCTION_WIDGET_NAME.body}} which will return the response body.

there are more options you can find in widget docs